# Reverse Factorials javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, reduce

I have a problem with create a function that takes any number and returns the number that it is a factorial of.
I'm trying to do this with the basic methods I know. I'm just starting to learn :D .

Examples

- 120 will return "5!"
- 24 will return "4!"
- 150 will return "None"

```js
function reverseFactorial(num) {
  let are = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  are.push(i)
   } 

  let multi = (acc, e) => {
    if (acc * e === num) {
      return are.length
    } else return "None"
  }
  are.reduce(multi, 1); 

};


console.log(reverseFactorial())
```

The Idea I got from @Nina Scholz is good but in this chelenge 150 will return "None". I appreciate any help. This can be done with this code ? Or do I need anything more advanced?

```js
function reverseFactorial(num) {
   let product = 1;
   let n = 1;
       
   while (product <= num) {
       if (product === num) {
          return `${n}!`
       } product *= ++n;
   }
  
}
```

Comment: `reverseFactorial` doesn’t return anything; the result of `are.reduce(multi, 1)` is never used. You’re not passing any argument to `reverseFactorial`. You’re most likely not using `reduce` correctly; please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: @Sebastian Simon  why? can you explain :) ?

Comment: are.reduce(multi, 1) is inside reverseFactorial, so its means I cant use reduce method inside another function ? When I try for example console.log(reverseFactorial(120)) i got undefined.

Comment: You get undefined because you don’t return anything from `reverseFactorial`. You’re not using `reduce` correctly, because you return `are.length` or the string `"None"` as the accumulator for the next iteration, but multiplying a string doesn’t make sense, and I’m not sure `are.length * e === num` is an intentional check.

Comment: simply add a return statement at the end of the function and return `'None'`. please see edit below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify your approach by using a single loop and return the value if the product is equal than the wanted value.

If not, go on until either found or greater than wanted.

If no value is found, return `'None'` at the end of the function.

```js
function reverseFactorial(num) {
   let product = 1,
       n = 1;
       
   while (product <= num) {
       if (product === num) return `${n}!`;
       product *= ++n;
   }
   return 'None';
}

console.log(reverseFactorial(24));  //   4!
console.log(reverseFactorial(120)); //   5!
console.log(reverseFactorial(150)); // None
```